# $1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$ and $1-2+3-4+5-6+7-\cdots$ and Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Some background. I was exploring the series expansion for $\ln(1+\cos x)$ in an attempt to expand it (at least, initially!) up to the third non-zero term, and along the way I unexpectedly stumbled upon the infinite series $1-1+1-1+...$ and $1-2+3-4+5-6+7-...$. Then I thought to expand it instead via a different method, as I had divergent series as coefficients which obviously wouldn't have helped in determining the terms exactly. The coefficients via this method (as expected) came out as reals, and I was then, out of curiosity, tempted to equate these respectively, arriving at a very unexpected (in this context) result: $1-1+1-1+1-1+1-...=\frac{1}{2}$ and $1-2+3-4+5-6+...=\frac{1}{4}$. What caught me as particularly surprising is that these are well-known results for the sums via other methodologies. The "proof" is below.

By Taylor's theorem, substituting the series for $\ln(1+x)$ and $\cos x$:

\begin{align}
\ln(1+\cos x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left({\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}}\right)^{n}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\cdots\right)^n\right)\\
\end{align}

We are only concerned with the first 3 terms overall, and terms whose order is 6 or above cannot contribute towards the coefficients of the lower order terms (0,2,4 in this case). So consider $\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^n$, ignoring order 6 or higher terms, for $n\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$:

\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^2
&=\ 1-\frac{2x^2}{2}+\frac{8x^4}{24}-\cdots\\
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^3
&=\ 1-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\frac{21x^4}{24}-\cdots\\
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^4
&=\ 1-\frac{4x^2}{2}+\frac{40x^4}{24}-\cdots\\
\end{align} and so on.

Conjecture that (from the patterns in the coefficients) $$\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^m=1-\frac{mx^2}{2}+\frac{am^2+bm+c}{24}x^4-\cdots$$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

We know some $x^4$ coefficients from the manual calculations, so we can solve for a, b, c (using m = 1, 2, 3):

$$a+b+c=1$$
$$4a+2b+c=8$$
$$9a+3b+c=21$$
$$\implies a=3,b=-2,c=0$$

$$\therefore\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^m=1-\frac{mx^2}{2}+\frac{3m^2-2m}{24}x^4-\cdots$$ for m = 1, 2, 3.

Assuming this as an inductive hypothesis for some $m\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$, we have:

\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^{m+1}
&=\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24})^m(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)\\
&=\left(1-\frac{mx^2}{2}+\frac{3m^2-2m}{24}x^4-\cdots\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{m+1}{2}x^2+\frac{3m^2-2m+6m+1}{24}x^4-\cdots\\
&=1-\frac{m+1}{2}x^2+\frac{3(m+1)^2-2(m+1)}{24}x^4-\cdots\\
\end{align}

$$\therefore\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)^m=1-\frac{mx^2}{2}+\frac{3m^2-2m}{24}x^4-\cdots\forall{m}\in\mathbb{Z_{>0}}$$ by mathematical induction.

Substituting this expansion back into the initial series expression, ignoring any terms in $x^6$ or higher (again because these terms will not contribute towards lower order coefficients):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24})^n\right)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(1-\frac{nx^2}{2}+\frac{3n^2-2n}{24}x^4\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}+\frac{x^4}{24}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(3n-2)(-1)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}+\frac{x^4}{24}\left(3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\right)\\
\end{align}

Now we've expressed the first 3 terms with the coefficients as series, let's expand it in a different way.

\begin{align}
\ln(1+\cos x)
&=\ln(2+(\cos x-1))\\
&=\ln\left(2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos x-1\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\ln2+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-1)\right)\\
&=\ln2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k}}{(2k)!}}\right)^n\right)\\
&=\ln2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}{n}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\cdots\right)^n\right)\\
&=\ln2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\cdots\right)-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\cdots\right)^2+\cdots\right)\\
\end{align}

Here, we can leave from consideration any of the order 6 or higher terms in the first "bracket", any of the order 4 or higher terms in the second "bracket" and all terms in any subsequent "bracket" for the purpose of our expansion (only looking for the first 3 terms). None of these will contribute towards the coefficients of the first few terms, as the power of the "bracket" is incrementing by 1 at each step. We get:

\begin{align}
\ln(1+\cos x)
&=\ln2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2+\cdots\right)\\
&=\ln2-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{96}+\cdots\\
\end{align}

Now that we have 2 different expressions for $\ln(1+\cos x)$, we can compare their coefficients:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}+\frac{x^4}{24}(3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1})=\ln2-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^4}{96}$$

From this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln2;$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}=-\frac{1}{4}\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{2};$$
$$\frac{1}{24}\left(3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\right)=-\frac{1}{96}$$
$$\implies3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}-2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{4}\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{4}$$

So the reason for the post was, why is it that this arrives at said conclusions, and where do the flaws in the method lie? What's the catch? These are obviously quite unintuitive (but interesting, nonetheless) values for such series, arrived at in a completely unforeseen (to me, at least) way. Would highly appreciate any clarifications/explanations.

P.S - I'm an A-level/high-school student, so if there are obvious issues then apologies; I haven't done any analysis yet.

Comment: The series $\sum (-1)^{n-1}$ is divergent, so it is incorrect to write $\sum (-1)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}$.  But what you show is that the series is **Abel summable** to the value $\frac12$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Taylor series of $\cos$ means you do $\log(1+y)$ around $y=1$ since $\cos 0=1$.

In particular the series there is only conditionally convergent (and only for $y \le 1$) so you cannot exchange summation as a series. However if you argue that you consider only values of $y<1$ and let $y \to 1$ you rediscover well-known summability results.

By Littlewood-Hardy Tauberian theorem they would become actual convergence results if $na_n$ is bounded, and note that for the first one $na_n= \pm 1$ so you actually have a true convergence result, but for the other two $na_n= \pm n, \pm n^2$ respectively, so there you do not get convergence, just summability as expected.

Comment: Could you clean this up a bit? As is, it's one really long and cluttered sentence.

Comment: sorry - it was supposed to be a comment (with space restrictions etc) and then it kind of got too long

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. what is the difference between convergence and summability? i did look up these series on wikipedia, and there were methods like Cesaro and Euler/Borel summation that were detailed; what is it about these methods that makes the answer obtained (of say 1+1-1+1-...=0.5) from them valid?

Comment: The convergence of a series is a fairly strong property requiring, for example, $a_n \to 0$, but there are many situations where you have a series with lots of "niceness" but which is not convergent and then using summability methods you can express that and assign a value to it; "Abelian" theorems show that convergent series are Abel or caesaro summable to the same sum as the usual one and Tauberian theorems give the converse under restrictions on the series terms; this is a vast and important area of classical and modern analysis; PNT is for example a Tauberian theorem at heart

Comment: intuitive is in the eye of the beholder - summability (of various kinds) is a very important tool and led to quite a lot of important results - one of the earliest and more striking was Feijer's famous theorem about the uniform Cesaro convergence of the Fourier series of a continuous function to the function itself (which is far from true for regular convergence)